# Prime checker doesn't include some multipliers of the number 10

Tags: c++, loops

I need to make a program that will check whether or not the number typed in (a) and its mirrored self (a1) are both prime numbers. I got it to work up to the point where I input a multiplier of 10, in which case it declares it as a prime number, which it clearly isn't.

I've already tried setting the condition:

> if ( a % 10 = 0 ) {//declare it as non prime}

After having done that, I would always get a return value of 0 after entering the number. Also tried declaring :

> if ( a == 1 ) {//declare it as a non prime}

which fixed it for multipliers of 10 up to 100, but the rest would give me the previously stated error.

My go at it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a, a1, DN;
  cin >> a;
  DN = a;
  a1 = 0;

  for (; a != 0;) {
    a1 *= 10;
    a1 = a1 + a % 10;
    a /= 10;
  }

  int este_prim, i, este_prim2;
  este_prim = 1;
  i = 2;
  este_prim2 = 1;
  while (i < DN && i < a1) {
    if (DN % i == 0) {
      este_prim = 0;
    }
    ++i;
  }

  if (a1 > i && a1 % i == 0) {
    este_prim2 = 0;
  }
  ++i;

  if (a == 1) {
    este_prim = 0;
  }
  if (a1 == 1) {
    este_prim2 = 0;
  }

  if (este_prim2 == 1 && este_prim == 1) {
    cout << "DA";
  } else {
    cout << "NU";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'm a complete newbie at this so any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: This may help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 1):

Your loop checks if DN is prime, but it doesn't check if a1 is prime.  And this block of code is something I do not understand.

```
if (a1 > i && a1 % i == 0) {
  este_prim2 = 0;
}
```

So just remove that.

Use this worthy helper function to detect if a positive number is prime:

```
bool isPrime(int x)
{
    if (x <= 1)
        return false;

    // 2 is the only even prime    
    if (x == 2)
        return true;

    // any other even number is not prime
    if ((x % 2) == 0)
        return false;

    // try dividing by all odd numbers from 3 to sqrt(x)    
    int stop = sqrt(x);

    for (int i = 3; i <= stop; i += 2)
    {
        if ((x % i) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then your code to detect if `DN` and it's mirror, `a1` are both prime is this:

```
int main() {
  int a, a1, DN;
  cin >> a;
  DN = a;
  a1 = 0;

  for (; a != 0;) {
    a1 *= 10;
    a1 = a1 + a % 10;
    a /= 10;
  }
  bool este_prim, este_prim2;
  este_prim = isPrime(DN);
  este_prim2 = isPrime(a1);
  if (este_prim2 && este_prim) {
    cout << "DA";
  } else {
    cout << "NU";
  }
}
```